# jQuery use data-src to change value of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, multiple-value

I'm using a `<select></select>` dropdown and I want to change the value of the div `#price`, however I need to use the value selector to send the data to another form. My question is can i use two options in the `value=""` or is it possible to use another selector such as the `data=""` below?

```
<select id="choose">
    <option value="test1" data="4.00">Test1</option>
    <option value="test2" data="6.00">Test2</option>
    <option value="test3" data="7.00">Test3</option>
</select>
<div id="price"></div>
```

The jQuery below only returns test1 test2 etc, how do i return a custom data value?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#choose').change(function(event) {
     jQuery('#price').html(jQuery('#choose').val());
  });
</script>
```

Thanks you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the selected option element using the [:selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) and then get the value of the data attribute

```
jQuery('#choose').change(function (event) {
    jQuery('#price').html(jQuery('#choose option:selected').attr('data'));
}).change(); //to iniitize the value on load
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CXp9u/)

---

But it will be better to use a data-* attribute

```
<select id="choose">
    <option value="test1" data-value="4.00">Test1</option>
    <option value="test2" data-value="6.00">Test2</option>
    <option value="test3" data-value="7.00">Test3</option>
</select>
<div id="price"></div>
```

then

```
jQuery('#choose').change(function (event) {
    jQuery('#price').html(jQuery('#choose option:selected').data('value'));
}).change();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mvx5w/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#choose').change(function(event) {
 jQuery('#price').html(jQuery('#choose option:selected').attr('data'));
});
</script>
```